# Using a WaveShaper to control Osc frequency results in no output

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

The issue:

Creating an audio graph as (poorly) illustrated below causes the oscillator to produce no output. I'm not sure whether the oscillator is producing ultra-low frequencies, or what, but no *audible* output is created.

`GainNode` -> `WaveShaper [-1, 1]` -> `GainNode` -> `OscillatorNode.frequency`

However, connecting the last GainNode in the above graph to another GainNode's `gain` param does *not* cause the same problem (assuming the final GainNode in this graph has an oscillator, or some sort of generator connected to it).
**EDIT: This is actually not true. It does have an impact. See the update below.**

`GainNode` -> `WaveShaper [-1, 1]` -> `GainNode` -> `GainNode.gain`

---

Examples:

I have created two JSFiddle's to show this in action.

- [The first is connected to an OscillatorNode's `frequency` param, and, when enabling the WaveShaperNode's `curve` property, the output is silenced.](https://jsfiddle.net/y6vLmkcu/5/)
- [The second is connected to a GainNode's `gain` param, and enabling/disabling the WaveShaperNode does *not* have an impact.](https://jsfiddle.net/yt7vnqgg/3/) **EDIT: This is actually not true. It does have an impact. See the update below.**

I think I'm either fundamentally misunderstanding the signal flow here, or something is going wrong at a lower level. Help!

---

A bit of background:

I'm attempting to create an audio graph in the WebAudio API that emulates the behaviour of the AudioParam object. The reason being that I want to be able to have an AudioParam with a custom curve, so I can control an AudioParam using built-in nodes (rather than a ScriptProcessingNode, which is intensive). I.e. have an exponentially curved AudioParam, or an equal-power AudioParam.

In the audio graphs above, the first `GainNode` is the "control" node, so changes to it's `gain.value` property will control the AudioParam emulation.

---

**Update (13/04)**

I added an AnalyserNode into the graph to visualise the output and I think I've found the problem...

The WaveShaperNode (using a linear curve with values [-1, 1]) clamps the input value to the range -1 to 1, regardless of the value going into it. So when the WaveShaperNode is enabled, the input from the `paramInput` GainNode is clamped to -1, 1. I need to look at the spec to see if this is the correct behaviour, but I'm thinking it might be; one of the main uses of the WaveShaperNode is for distortion, so if it *didn't* clamp input signals to -1, 1 there would be no distortion produced, just shaping. Need to check this.

[Here's an updated JSFiddle showing the osc's frequency using an analyser node. Apologies for the rough code.](https://jsfiddle.net/y6vLmkcu/10/)

[And here's an updated JSFiddle showing the same behaviour when controlling a GainNode's gain param](https://jsfiddle.net/y6vLmkcu/12/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WaveShaper.curve spec](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#attributes-22) is pretty clear.  The input is clamped to [-1, 1].  You'll need to map your input to that range using, perhaps, a gain node to reduce the amplitude to unity at most.

Comment: Yep, I feel a little silly for asking this question, now. In the back of my mind, I knew that, but for some reason I just didn't think! I'd like to delete this question, but maybe I should leave it up in case anyone else might find it useful?